# Using Ternary Function in Associative Array (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, ternary-operator

I'd like to understand if it's a) possible and b) "side-effect free" to assign associative array elements using a ternary function in PHP.

So instead of this:

```
$second_element = $test ? "tistrue" : "tisfalse";
echo build_assignment_page(array(
  'firstkey'  => $first_element,
  'secondkey' => $second_element,
  'thirdkey'  => $third_element
 ));
```

Something like this:

```
echo build_assignment_page(array(
  'firstkey'  => $first_element,
  'secondkey' => ($test ? "tistrue" : "tisfalse"),
  'thirdkey'  => $third_element
 ));
```

Comment: @PaulCrovella I expected it to work, but it did not appear to be; eventually the culprit turned up elsewhere ($test was incorrectly returning false)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **ternary operator** can be used everywhere where an expression is allowed. (It is **not** a construct like `if..else` or `while`).

Therefore, your code is valid.

The ternary operator never has side effects. It checks if the condition evaluates to `true` or some true-ish value. Then it returns a value, depending on the condition.